# jQuery Slide Inner div from right to left

Tags: slidetoggle, jquery

Here's what I've got so far:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phantasmix/nAaMV/4/)

**CSS:**

```
#button-top { width: 100px; position: absolute; left: 75%; top: 40px; padding-left: 100px;overflow: hidden;}
#button-top:hover, #button-bottom:hover {cursor: pointer;}
.slide { position: relative; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; width: 350px; }
.slide img {position: relative; z-index: 100;}
.slide p {width: 80px; padding:8px 16px; color: #fff; margin: 0; }
.innerTop, .innerBottom { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 10px; width: 200px; height: 90px; padding: 6px; background: url(http://i39.tinypic.com/nz4ldw.png) 0 0 no-repeat; z-index: 50; display: none; }

#button-bottom { width: 100px; position: absolute; left: 75%; top: 240px; padding-left: 100px;overflow: hidden;}
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('#button-top').click(function() {
  $('.innerTop').toggle('slide');
});
$('#button-bottom').click(function() {
  $('.innerBottom').toggle('slide');      
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hide-mobile" id="button-top">
[IMG]
<div class="slide innerTop"><p>HIDDEN SLIDING CONTENT</p></div>
</div>

<div class="hide-mobile" id="button-bottom">
[IMG]
<div class="slide innerBottom"><p>HIDDEN SLIDING CONTENT</p></div>
</div>
```

I'd like the blue inner div to slide from RIGHT to LEFT.

Comment: you can try this tutorial for better result

http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done using animate function. Here is the solution:

```
$('#button-top').toggle(function() {
  $('.innerTop').animate({'left':'3px'});
}, function() {
 $('.innerTop').animate({'left':'103px'});
});


$('#button-bottom').toggle(function() {
  $('.innerBottom').animate({'left':'3px'});
}, function() {
 $('.innerBottom').animate({'left':'103px'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nAaMV/6/

Comment: Haris, thanks for that, but then the blue div becomes visible to the right of the button. That was part of my original issue. Is there a way to only show the blue div once it gets to the left of the button?

Comment: This is nearly perfect. I was thinking - is it possible to combine animate with fade? So that when it's going back to the right, the blue tab is faded out.

Comment: The Sliding Effect on this page does what I need: http://veselov.sumy.ua/uploads/files/demo/020/test.htm

But I don't know how to adapt it to my 2 button instances

Comment: when I'm allowed to click the up-arrows, I'll return and give you points for this. I decided to go with the pull-tabs that slide out of view completely but your solution is also very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
// Set the options for the effect type chosen
var options = { direction: 'right' };

// Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
var duration = 700;

$('#button-top').click(function() {
      $('.innerTop').toggle('slide', options, duration);
});
$('#button-bottom').click(function() {
      $('.innerBottom').toggle('slide', options, duration);      
});
```

- Please make sure to include the [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/download/all/) file in your code, like I have included in the fiddle    
  ( *See the checkbox for the jQuery UI 1.9.2 checked in right side* ).

[**FIDDLE DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/nAaMV/8/) or [**FIDDLE DEMO #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/nAaMV/9/)