# Make 2 actions with the same element

Tags: jquery, animation

As you can see here:

http://jsbin.com/maxov/1/watch?html,css,js,output

Once I click the button, the hidden div moves to the left, but what I also need to do, is when i press the button again the div has to go back to it's original position, but I don't know how to do that.

i tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".div").animate({
       left: "0px"

   }, 300);
    $("body").animate({
       left:"150px"
    }, 300);
});
```

the below doesn't work

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $(".div").animate ( {
       left: "-150px"
   }, 300);
    $("body").animate({
       left:"0px"
    }, 300)
});
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779639/jquery-slide-inner-div-from-right-to-left) question can help in your case

Comment: @DoanCuong - Nooooo! That version of toggle used in the answer posted in that question is deprecated and removed from jQuery and should not be recommended.

Comment: @adeneo thank for your notice, I haven't use jquery for a long time ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the state in  a variable and use it to show or hide.

```
var visible = false;

$("button").click(function() {
  if (visible) {
   $(".div").animate({
       left: "-150px"

   }, 300);
   $("body").animate({
       left:"0px"
   }, 300)
  } else {
    $(".div").animate({
       left: "0px"
   }, 300);
   $("body").animate({
       left:"150px"
   }, 300);
  }

  visible = !visible;
});
```

Comment: I would make variable state change like: visible = !visible; at the end of click function, outside if.

Comment: That works wonderfully, but i don't how it works can you explain it please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $(".div").animate({
        left: flag ? "-150px" : "0px"
    }, 300);

    $("body").animate({
        left: flag ? "0px" : "150px"
    }, 300);

    $(this).data('flag', !flag)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/97962ghn/)